# Overflow: auto scrollbar and dynamic width

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a box with content-based width (position: absolute). But "overflow-y: auto" inserts a scrollbar that doesn't make container wider unlike the "overflow-y: scroll". I need auto overflow and auto width including scrollbar. Is there a solution?

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mw552cxf/

Answer (score 1):

try to add `overflow: hidden;` to each item :

```
.item {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Edit : ok so the solution who sweets your need wold be this , use [word-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap):

```
.item {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mw552cxf/1/)**

**[Live Demo 2nd solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mw552cxf/3/)**

Comment: Then their content is cut

Comment: Breaking words doesn't suit me :)

Answer (score 0):

How about adjusting the width of `.container` in the CSS?

Comment: No, i need dynamic content-based width